# How to install VeriSign's Intermediate CA Certificates?

Tags: tomcat, certificate, solaris

I'm running tomcat on Solaris server and I would like to know how can install VeriSign's Intermediate CA certificates?

I have been struggling for days and keep having *keytool error: java.io.EOFException*
How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net). It's a graphical user interface to the java certificate management api.
Also you should make sure that the certificate does not contain unneccessary whitespaces.